# Objective-c Macro Language detection

Tags: objective-c, macros

I want a macro with the language in in. Currently the code is:

```objectivec
#define APP_LOCALE_X @([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"nl_NL"]);
#ifdef APP_LOCALE_X
    #define APP_LOCALE @"&locale=nl_NL"
#else
    #define APP_LOCALE @"&locale=en_US"
#endif
```

Logically this will not work since `#ifdef` sees the macro defined. I can't seem to wrap my head around the Macro logic.

The other option would be to have a macro with the APP_LOCALE_X and a string. Like this: Obviously this is pseudo code:

```objectivec
#define APP_LOCALE_X @([[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]) == "nl_NL");
#define APP_LOCALE @"&locale="APP_LOCALE_X
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? what is your ultimate goal? show an example of hypothetic usage

Comment: Remember, such macros are simply compile-time text replacements. You are trying to do a runtime check with macros. Just write a normal function that you call at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator inside macro for condition instead of #ifdef:

```
#define APP_LOCALE ([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"nl_NL"] ? @"&locale=nl_NL" : @"&locale=en_US")
```

If you want to have boolean value extracted to a separate variable you can do it the following way:

```
#define APP_LOCALE_X [[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"nl_NL"]
#define APP_LOCALE (APP_LOCALE_X ? @"&locale=nl_NL" : @"&locale=en_US")
```

Please note that in your example you placed semicolon `;` after #define statement, you should not place it there, as it will be inserted when expanding macro.